# Elixir error with genserver.call timeout db connection

Tags: erlang, timeout, elixir, erlang-otp

after i installed wxWidgets libs and reinstall my version of erlang otp to can i run ":observer.start",  my application come fails with this error:
i'm use evm to manage my erlang otp versions.

```
[info] GET /dashboard/admin
[error] #PID<0.1290.0> running DashboardWeb.Endpoint (cowboy_protocol) terminated
Server: test.lvh.me:5000 (http)
Request: GET /dashboard/admin
** (exit) exited in: :gen_server.call(#PID<0.797.0>, {:checkout, #Reference<0.3971714438.3053715457.259419>, true, 15000}, 5000)
   ** (EXIT) time out
```

i researched to try solve error and i finded this link "https://github.com/elixir-ecto/db_connection/issues/127", but i can't solve error, i use elixir 1.6.6 and erlang otp 20.3, i install erlang otp 21.0 like link mention but not work, anyone solved this issue?

Comment: Please post the full error message: what comes after `time out`?

Comment: is the complete error, terminal don't show more error info. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GS8YVbbxx2/